# How do I fill nail holes in baseboards?

Tags: finishing, baseboard, hardwood-refinishing

While installing a new floor in my living room I had to remove the baseboards (finished wood, not painted), now that the job is done and the baseboards have been replaced what is the best way to fill the nail holes?

What steps should I take to fill the holes, add stain (to match), and polyurethane so the holes are not noticeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The make wood putty in a [range of colors](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?keyword=wood+putty&langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) to match different types of wood.  You can probably find one that's a close match to your baseboards.

Take a small amount, fill the nail hole and wipe it smooth with a damp cloth.  When it dries, lightly sand it and the surrounding area down, then re-varnish the area.